# Best solution for lossy compression of a large amount (>10Tb) of volumetric data (astrophysics simulations)

Tags: compression, volume

I work on large simulations of astrophysics (galaxy formation) and I have a problem of data management. In fact these simulations produce a very large amount of volumetic data (physical quantities on 3d cells (like 3d pixels)). My question is quite simple : what is, according to you, the best solution to compress such data (lossy compression).

What I need is :
- Adjustable lossy 3D compression
- I don't need a "ready-to-use" solution, but an open-source lib/code that I can adapt to my simulation code
- Ability to work on a large amount of data

(the solution may come from libraries of image/volumetric image compression)

Thank you very much.

EDIT : This is not for plotting/displaying these data, this is for really reducing the weight of these data (because if I can reduce the weigth, I can write more time step of the simulation on disk, and so better resolve the dynamic of galaxies in post-processing)

Comment: Well, it's lossy compression, so what are you willing to lose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if this is what you are looking for as this is not exactly compression and will not reduce the amount of data on your disk. But it can be used to simplify presentation and computation.

A solution for presentation of large datasets is using a [LOD](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_Detail) implementation. They are per definition lossy, and some are adjustable. There are some continuous (and adjustable) LOD algorithms implemented [**here**](http://vterrain.org/Doc/clod.html) and [**here**](http://gts.sourceforge.net/)

EDIT : you could actually use LOD as a compression method, if you store the output of the algorithm, but it would certainly be far from being the most efficient compression strategy

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's difficult to answer without knowing the actual format and build-rule  of your data.

Chances are that, with such raw quantities, the format is quite compressible (when i hear 3D pixels, i expect that).

So your best guess would be to "cut" the source data into blocks which size is natural to the format you're analyzing, and compress each block independently. You will then decompress each block when you need it.

If the raw data proves very compressible (lots of zeros for example), you can get some very good results with this simple method.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and the "solution" I've come up with is to use off-the-shelf video compression by converting one of the spatial dimensions to time. Not pretty, but so much work has been done on video compression (not to mention hardware support) that it is hard to beat.

Answer (score 0):

currently I also work on 3D point reduction/compression (but with terristic data) and my solution was to use the [OctoMap](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap) framework and to [extend it with geometrical point distribution models](http://eugenfunk.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/3d-points-as-surfels/). Using the OcTree properties and the hierarchical distribution aproximation from Scattered Data Approximation it is possible to implement an LOD approach with high accuracies on lower detail levels.